Can Lost Isle Calling's activated ability be copied effectively?
I would love some clarification on how exactly Lost Isle Calling's activated ability works.
First off, since the cost of the ability involves sacrificing LIC itself, how can the ability count how many verse counters are on it? LIC was sacrificed, so obviously it has no counters on it. Does the ability only check for the counters as it's being put on the stack (right before LIC actually disappears) and never again?
Second, if I try to copy this ability with Three Rings for the Elven-Kings (Rings of Brighthearth), will the copy count the same amount of verse counters as the original ability (and possibly generate a second extra turn), or will there be some sort of error since LIC was sacrificed to pay for the original ability?
Thanks

The copied ability should work like normal.
The ability is able to go off of the number of counters on Lost Isle Calling when it was last on the battlefield:

608.2h If an effect requires information from the game (such as the number of creatures on the battlefield), the answer is determined only once, when the effect is applied. If the effect requires information from a specific object, including the source of the ability itself, the effect uses the current information of that object if it’s in the public zone it was expected to be in; if it’s no longer in that zone, or if the effect has moved it from a public zone to a hidden zone, the effect uses the object’s last known information.

This would apply just the same to a copy of the ability. The ability itself is not linked to the object that created it, so the only “link” is that the ability refers to “Lost Isle Calling” (which means the specific Lost Isle Calling that was sacrificed to activate the ability).
A copy of the ability also refers to “Lost Isle Calling”, and it is referring to the same one as the original ability:

707.10. To copy a spell, activated ability, or triggered ability means to put a copy of it onto the stack; a copy of a spell isn’t cast and a copy of an activated ability isn’t activated. A copy of a spell or ability copies both the characteristics of the spell or ability and all decisions made for it, including modes, targets, the value of X, and additional or alternative costs. (See rule 601, “Casting Spells.”) Choices that are normally made on resolution are not copied. If an effect of the copy refers to objects used to pay its costs, it uses the objects used to pay the costs of the original spell or ability.

